# Brightness at minimum all the time

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio, brightness

I have a Sony Vaio with Windows 8 and the brightness is at the minimum level all the time. If I increase it with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> it immediately reverts back to minimum. I am not sure what to do next. 
I have tried control panel, power options and changing it directly there, but I get the same result.

What would cause this? How can I fix brightness to be adjustable to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely happening due to the Windows 8 "*adaptive brightness*" option being enabled.

Follow [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/107173/disable-windows-8s-adaptive-brightness-to-fix-dark-screen-problems/) to disable it (the link includes screenshots]:

> - Open up the Windows desktop with Win+D, click the power management icon in the tray, and then choose More power options from the menu.
>
>   Note that you could also use the Metro search screen to get to the
>     Power Options panel.
> - Once here, click the “Change plan settings” link on the selected plan.
> - Then click the “Change advanced power settings” link.
> - And now, browse down to Display –> Enable adaptive brightness, and change the settings there to Off.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my old Sony Vaio. 
The problem is something wrong with Windows 8 drivers (It happens to Windows 10 as well). But no new drivers avaiable for this old models.

The solution I found (after digging quite long in Google) is not so complicated:

1. Open Regedit.exe
2. Find this key:

   `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class
   \{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001 (or 0000)`
3. Look for this key: "**FeatureTestControl**"
4. Change its value to:

   - "**fb20**" (hexadecimal value) if you have integrated Intel Graphics or
   - "**fb60**" if you have a NVIDIA Graphics card.
5. Restart Windows

PS: Its wise to make [backup of your registry](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-registry#1TC=windows-7) before making any change.